# Configure cloudflare subdomains for mailchimp

Tags: domain-name-system, email, domain, subdomain, cname-record

I've managed to successfully configure mailchimp with cloudflare (using CNAME and TXT records as advised here: https://bobandedovic.com/blog/technology/how-to-authenticate-a-domain-name-on-mailchimp-using-cloudflare-cname-bypass-solution).

The problem is that I need it to work for subdomains instead (e.g. email.[mydomain].com).

I'm reluctant to just play about with the DNS records until it works since I appreciate the DNS takes time to refresh and I don't want to have to re-authenticate with mailchimp every time.

### **Question**

Does anybody know how the CNAME and TXT records should look when using subdomains as opposed to just the root?

For example, CNAME is currently:

`k1._domainkey` (pointing to `dkim.mcsv.net`)

Should this be:

`k1._domainkey.[mySubDomain]` instead?

And TXT file is currently:

`[myDomain].com` (pointing to `v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net`)

Should this be:

`[mySubDomain].[myDomain].com` instead?

Any help or pointers in the right direction very much appreciated with this one, in desperate need of getting it configured asap.

Comment: Hi, if you're satisfied with my answer, please accept the answer as the correct one, that way your question doesn't pop up as unanswered! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SPF (the TXT record) you just add the subdomain in front of the record

```
[mysubdomain].example.com TXT v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net
```

Remember to add a policy after, like ~all so that the record has any effect.

For DKIM, you add the subdomain after the selector._domainkey. part, so you got it absolutely right.

```
k1._domainkey.[mySubDomain].example.com TXT v=DKIM1 [Mailchimp Stuff]
```

You can use mxtoolbox.com to check that you got the records right, the selector that Mailchimp uses is k1.

Also remember that if you later want to implement DMARC for your root, make sure to get the option for subdomains right (normal procedure is to implement DMARC at the root and set the policy as reject for all subdomains).

EDIT:

Cloudflare want's you to input them as this (Mandrill as an example):

```
example.com  TXT  v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all
mandrill._domainkey.example.com  TXT  v=DKIM1\; (values from Mandrill)
```

I've edited the samles above to align with this.

Mxtoolbox SPF https://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx

Mxtoolbox DKIM https://mxtoolbox.com/dkim.aspx

Here's a few articles on StackExchange that goes into a bit more detail.

[Setting up SPF and DKIM records of a subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/851215/setting-up-spf-and-dkim-records-of-a-subdomain)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420929/spf-for-subdomain