# How do I prevent the SPF_HELO_NONE warning when sending from Postfix?

Tags: postfix, smtp, spf, spamassassin

When using a tool like https://dkimvalidator.com/ to verify configuration of DKIM, SPF, DMARC, etc. for sending mail from a web server, I get a warning like this:

> 0.0 SPF_HELO_NONE SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record

It seems like a bad signal even though the score isn't really affected. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Publish SPF records for HELO/EHLO hostnames**

The Sender Policy Framework does not only protect `MAIL FROM`, but also `HELO`. Whereas the *`MAIL FROM` identity* MUST be verified ([RFC 7208, 2.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7208#section-2.4)), the verification of the *`HELO` identity* is only RECOMMENDED ([RFC 7208, 2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7208#section-2.3)). This is the reason Spamassassin ([`rules/25_spf.cf`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk/rules/25_spf.cf)), where this scoring comes from, only gives `0.0` by default.

In your own answer, you suggest changing the HELO hostname to match the domain, but that is not the only solution – and not the best solution in all cases. Some receiving systems gives negative scoring if the hostname in the `HELO` command does not match with the *reverse DNS* `PTR` record ([SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch)). This is why you might want to add an SPF record for your `HELO` hostname, instead. (SPF FAQ / Common mistakes / [Publish SPF records for HELO/EHLO names used by your mail servers](http://www.open-spf.org/action_browse_id_FAQ/Common_mistakes_revision_26/#helo).)

**Publish SPF records for *every* hostname**

Furthermore, every hostname with an `A` record that is not intended for sending email should be protected with SPF, too. Otherwise, anyone can use them as an *envelope sender*. (SPF FAQ / Common mistakes / [Publish null SPF records for your domains that don't send mail](http://www.open-spf.org/action_browse_id_FAQ/Common_mistakes_revision_26/#all-domains); related [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/851254/274176).)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. My `PTR` already matches, and I do publish `-all` SPF for mail-less domains. Mine is a case of `machine-name.domain.example` being the domain I used when setting up the web server that serves `domain.example`.

Answer (score 4):

It was as simple as adding the below setting in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtp_helo_name = $mydomain
```

The message changes to this:

> -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS          SPF: HELO matches SPF record

Comment: Great, this fixes it! But it appears to add another issue: `Your reverse DNS does not match with your sending domain.`, as the HELO banner uses `example.com` instead of the correct `mail.example.com`.

Comment: @strarsis See the other answer, this works for me because my PTR/rDNS matches. You need to change that record, which is controlled by your hosting service/network provider, not part of your domain's records. Or change your HELO to be the same as your existing rDNS record.